# curl not respecting certificate that Firefox is Ok with

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate

Have a customer that is using a webhook from a supplier (I am the dev in the middle) and the supplier is not trusting the certificate that is presented by the F5 that is proxying the request, at least that appears to be the problem, as the supplier is a little vague about the error.

They said to use curl to POST to test it out. The curl response, with the --insecure option, is as follows

```
Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Pennsylvania; L=Conshohocken; O=NNNNNNNNN; CN=xxxxxxxx.yyy.com
*  start date: Sep  6 21:44:45 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 30 21:44:45 2023 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2012 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
```

if I browse to it using firefox the cert appears to be trusted

[image]

If I explicitly go to https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html and download the pem file and use the --cacert curl option to use it, it still gives the same error.

If I then go to https://www.entrust.com/resources/certificate-solutions/tools/root-certificate-downloads and download the root cert and chain for the L1K Authority and add it to the pem file that I downloaded it all work Ok.

Probably just a misunderstanding on my part but why does FF trust it without the additional pem file/why do I need to add this for curl to work.

I did find that Edge trusts it as well, and looking the the local cert store I do not see the L1K as a trusted root cert there either

Comment: Probably you need to place the root certificate and chain into `/etc/ssl/certs` and retry again

Comment: @TelinovDmitri yes I understand that. I was effectively doing that when I specified the --cacert option. The question was more related to why does FF trust it and curl doesn't when they are using the same trusted ca list (at least I think they are).
I have the customer saying "we use entrust, surely you trust their CA's" and the webhook service guys saying curl doesn't trust it, which is not really a curl issue, more the pem file used.
I don't even know if the customer's system actually uses curl or if they just use it as a tester. I am not in control of the webhook source, but have asked.

Comment: Firefox has it's own list of trusted certificates.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes I realise that. How I got to this point was that the curl troubleshooting section suggests that to ensure you have the latest list, go to the Mozilla web site, which it links to, and get a pem that has the latest list used by FF. (currently updated Oct 2022)

After doing this curl still fails to trust the site, whereas FF does. If I add the L1K chain and root cert to the file it works.
If I look at the FF trusted root authorities it does not include the L1K yet still works. Am confused about the different mechanisms in place here

Comment: You should be confused, it's confusing. Different entities have different policies regarding which certificate authorities they trust. Google Chrome relies on whatever platform it's running on to provide the trusted roots. Mozilla bundles their own trusted roots with their products. Java has its own set.